# How to link on Visual Studio 2015 to FFTW?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, linker, libraries, fftw

I follow provided [tutorial](http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html): downloaded, unpacked, `lib /verbose  /machine:x86 /def:libfftw3-3.def`. I have 3 main files `libfftw3-3.lib`, `fftw3.h`, `libfftw3-3.dll`. I created empty console Win32 project. I set up my include and libs folder to fftw dir for all configurations, add `libfftw3-3.lib` to additional dependencies. I add simple code:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fftw3.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Now its time to compile, output is simple and sad:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: FFTWConsole, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  Source.cpp
1>libfftw3-3.lib : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x358
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

What shall I do& How to use FFTW on windows in MSVC project under Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: If a file was not detected MSVC would output another error eg: `1>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'libfftw3aaa-3.lib'`

Comment: Did you download the 32 or 64 bit binaries? The 64 bit ones will not work for a 32 bit application.

Comment: I tested 32 bit binaries with win32 project and x64 with x64 project - result is the same, even tried to do it all over in Visual Studio 2012 - same error=(